# Spring UnknownServiceException

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have scheduled task in separate thread that access @Transactional service. 
In this task I try to access method like this

```
List<Obj> objects = new ArrayList<Obj>(objService.getObjWithStatus(Status.PROCESSING));
```

and sometimes get the exception

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:544)

Caused by: org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
```

I tried to synchronize access to the service over all threads, but exception still occures randomly. Is there any way to prevent this kind of error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that spring doesn't close scheduled tasks on exit, and they are keep running without context. Adding

```
@PreDestroy
private void destroyListener() {
    synchronized (this) {
        scheduledTask.cancel(false);
    }
}
```

seems to fix this issue